# can I update a javascript variable being displayed using innerhtml

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to build a basic budget calculator tool in javascript which displays a running total at the top of the page which updates when individual budget items are changed. To do this I'm using [`document.getElementById("runningTotal").innerHTML += total_sp;`]. This works fine for calculating the running total but every time I make a change the new total is appended to the old total, so the output on screen makes no sense. Can anyone tell me how I can do this so that the running total updates every time a change is made replacing the old total with the new total? I'm new to all this, so very grateful for any help you can offer. Cheers!

```
<script>
    // defining pre-change spending levels
    var research_sp = 217200
    var wage_sp = 155000
    var total_sp = wage_sp + research_sp
    function changeresearchspending() {
        var nameElement = document.getElementById("researchcalc");
        //defining percentage change to research spending levels
        var research_r = nameElement.value;
        var research_ch = research_r * research_sp;
        var research_sp_end = research_sp + research_ch;
        total_sp = total_sp + research_ch
        document.getElementById("researchChange").innerHTML += research_ch;
        document.getElementById("endresearchTotal").innerHTML += research_sp_end;
        document.getElementById("endTotalSpend1").innerHTML += total_sp;
        document.getElementById("runningTotal").innerHTML += total_sp;
    }
    function changewagespending() {
        var nameElement = document.getElementById("wagecalc");
        //defining percentage change to wage spending levels
        var wage_r = nameElement.value;
        var wage_ch = wage_r * wage_sp;
        var wage_sp_end = wage_sp + wage_ch;
        total_sp = total_sp + wage_ch
        document.getElementById("wageChange").innerHTML += wage_ch;
        document.getElementById("endwageTotal").innerHTML += wage_sp_end;
        document.getElementById("endTotalSpend2").innerHTML += total_sp;
        document.getElementById("runningTotal").innerHTML += total_sp;
    }
</script>

<div id="runningTotal">
    SPENDING (RUNNING TOTAL) £
</div>
<br>
<div id="startresearchTotal">
    Baseline research spending is: £
    <script>document.write(research_sp)</script>
    <br><br>
    Baseline wage spending is: £
    <script>document.write(wage_sp)</script>
    <br><br>
    Baseline total spending is: £
    <script>document.write(total_sp)</script>
</div>
<br>
<input id="researchcalc" type="number">
<input type="button" value="change research spend" onClick="changeresearchspending()">
<div id="researchChange">
    <br> Change in research spending is: £
</div>
<div id="endresearchTotal">
    <br> New research spending is: £
</div>
<div id="endTotalSpend1">
    <br> New total spending is: £
</div>
</div>
<br>
<input id="wagecalc" type="number">
<input type="button" value="change wage spend" onClick="changewagespending()">
<div id="wageChange">
    <br> Change in wage spending is: £
</div>
<div id="endwageTotal">
    <br> New wage spending is: £
</div>
<div id="endTotalSpend2">
    <br> New total spending is: £
</div>
```

Comment: using  `var += var2` is the same as `var = var + var2`. what you want is a straight assignment (`var = var2`) instead of an additional assignment which you have. If you keep incrementing on every change you will end up with weird numbers, unless you are trying to only ever add.

Comment: cheers! Thanks for the edits to the cose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the += by =, like this:

```
document.getElementById("runningTotal").innerHTML = total_sp;
```